# Problemas para obtener width y height de una imagen insertada con append

Tags: html, jquery

Pagina html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
 <head>
 <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>     
    <div id='resultado'></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src= "js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var numMiniaturas=4;
     for( var i=1; i<=numMiniaturas;i++){
         var newListItem= "<img id='imagen"+i+"' 
          src='http://img2.rtve.es/v/1451521/'' />";
          $('#resultado').append(newListItem);
     }
     var filas=numMiniaturas/2;
     var columnas=numMiniaturas/2;
     var height = $('#imagen1').height();
     var width = $('#imagen1').width();
     alert(height);
     alert(width);
   });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los alert me muestran 0.
Asi queda el código al cargar la pagina. Creo que cuando intento obtener la altura y anchura de una de las imagenes todavia no se ha insertado.
Alguna solución?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el `.load()` para que cuando se cargue la imagen te de el width y height.

```
$("#imagen1").load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
```